# slurm, srun and parallelism

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, batch-processing, slurm

I have seen the following two very similar schemes used when submitting jobs with multiple steps to slurm:

On the one hand you can do

```
#SBATCH -N1 -c1 -n5 # 5 tasks in total on 1 node, 1 cpu per task
for j in {1..4}; do
    srun --exclusive -n1 script $j &
done
srun --exclusive -n1 script 5
wait
```

On the other hand you can do

```
#SBATCH -N1 -c1 -n5 # 5 tasks in total on 1 node, 1 cpu per task
for j in {1..5}; do
    srun --exclusive -n1 script $j &
done
wait
```

Because the job should have only 5 CPUs allocated to it I don't really
understand how the second one can work correctly, since after 
four job steps have been started with srun there is no way the scheduler can allocate a fifth job 'in the background' and then return to the original script... where would the original script run? (I admit my knowledge of these things is pretty limited though).

However, I have personally tested both ways and they both seem to work exactly the same. The second script is a bit simpler in my opinion, and when dealing with somewhat larger input scripts this can be an advantage, but I'm worried that I don't understand 100% what is going on here. Is there a preferred way to do this? What is the difference? What is Bash/slurm doing behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

They both work the same in principle, though the second one is clearer (and correct - see below). Each invocation of `srun` will run `script` on a separate CPU (probably - though if it runs very fast they could run on a subset of the sbatch-allocated CPUs).

I think the first example doesn't need `wait`, since the last command isn't run in the background.

By the way, the first example has an error: `%j` is local to the for-loop, so the last run inside the loop and the run outside the loop both invoke `script 4`.

Comment: `wait` is needed in all cases, because the job started in the foreground could finish before the jobs started in the background. Without the `wait`, you risk killing the 4 background jobs when the foreground job finishes.

Comment: I edited the error, thank you, you are right. I guess what confuses me is that in the script it seems as if the fifth srun invocation will run the script on a separate CPU and then, due to &, try to return control to the main batch script, but there will be no more CPU's left for the main batch script to run on, since all of the srun calls are --exclusive, right? My best guess is that since there are no cpu's available bash just blocks and doesn't return control until one becomes available and only then runs wait, but I wanted to make sure that this is what is actually happening.

Comment: It is not `bash` that blocks, but `srun`. The `--exclusive` parameter causes `srun` to wait until some resource is available. Meanwhile, `bash` allows the `srun` process to run in the background (to run waiting for free resources).

Comment: @Poshi your second comment increased my confusion slightly. If I understand correctly then in the second example srun runs 4 times but when it tries to run the fifth time it can't, since the control was returned to bash, which runs wait, so at that point there are 4 CPUs running the srun scripts and 1 CPU running bash, which makes it so that the fifth call has to wait for the first srun script to finish? This doesn't seem right, since running sleep 10 in the scripts finishes in 10 seconds, not 20.

Comment: No. In both examples, `wait` runs at the end, so in the second example `srun` run 5 times in the background and then `wait` is executed. You asked for 5 tasks (`-n 5`), so the five `srun` can run at once, as there are free resources for them. Meanwhile, the `wait` waits for them to finish.